# Estimating Amazon products price

Tags: web-scraping, e-commerce, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to develop an AI tool that can price items based on information of online products found on Amazon, JD etc (unfortunately I can't access the prices of those platforms due their strict anti-web scraping capabilities)  . I'm not looking for something super accurate. I just need the program to be able to allocate a reasonable price that's not too far off from what you would expect in reality. Are there existing solutions for this kind of applications?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have access to amazon product api, your best bet is to use some other free/paid third-party public API. In our startup we use [amazon-price](https://rapidapi.com/ebappa1971/api/amazon-price) from RapidAPI, it supports up to 1000 products in a single request. We've tried other options but most of them don't support bulk price and/or are more expensive possibly due to the fact that they also provide other data apart from just price.